# Why component with Context Provider doesn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I was looking for the answer why react component with Context Provider doesn't re-render but i couldn't find answer proper for me to understand why.
Moreover i want to mention Im using GatsbyJS.

Here's `App.context.js`:

```
const defaultValue = {
  menu: false,
  handleMenu: () => { },
}

const AppContext = createContext(defaultValue);

export default AppContext;

export { defaultValue };
```

Next, down below there's Provider element `App.provider.js`:

```
import AppContext, { defaultValue } from './App.context';

class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = defaultValue
  }

  handleMenu = () => {
    if (this.state.menu) {
      this.setState({
        menu: false
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        menu: true
      })
    }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{
        menu: this.state.menu,
        handleMenu: this.handleMenu,
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

Then, I'm using this provider at the beginning of elements tree:

```
//Components
import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';
import MainWrap from '../components/mainWrap';

//Context
import AppProvider from '../context/App.provider';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

    return (
            <AppProvider>
                <MainWrap>
                    <Header />
                        {children}
                    <Footer />
                </MainWrap>
            </AppProvider>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Here's MainWrap component:

```
//Styles
import wrapStyles from '../styles/wrapper.module.scss';

//Context
import AppContext from '../context/App.context';

const MainWrap = ({children}) => {

  const {menu} = useContext(AppContext);
  
  return ( 
    <div className={menu?wrapStyles.wrap:wrapStyles.wrapActive}>{children}</div>
   );
}
 
export default MainWrap;
```

When context value change, child components like MainPage re-render properly, but why component with Provider does not, so i can't instead of using next wrap component (MainPage) just put a div in component with Provider:

```
//Components
import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';

//Styles
import wrapStyles from '../styles/wrapper.module.scss';

//Context
import AppProvider from '../context/App.provider';
import AppContext from '../context/App.context';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

    const {menu} = useContext(AppContext);

    return (
            <AppProvider>
                <div className={menu?wrapStyles.wrap:wrapStyles.wrapActive}>
                    <Header />
                        {children}
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </AppProvider>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

I hope it will be understandable.

Comment: Any solution you found? I've a similar situation